# Filter sunspot search by class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I've set up a sunspot/solr search with rails that works like a charme:

```
# run the search
search_results = Sunspot.search Project, Question, User, Requests do
  fulltext params[:search]

  paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 10
end
```

It could be cool to filter that search results by a given class. E.g.there is a param in the URL like `params[:class]`, it would be awesome if the search would only consist of results from that specific class (Project, Question, User, Requests...).

I just can't figure out where to start at.

Hope someone could help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. All you need to do is adding the class as a string to the searchable block:

```
# solr search
searchable do
  text :firstname, :lastname, :email, :position
  integer :account_id
  string :klass
end

def klass
  return self.class.to_s.downcase
end
```

After that you're able to filter by the class (klass)

```
# run the search
search_results = Sunspot.search Project, Question, User do
  fulltext params[:search]
  with :account_id, params[:account_id]
  with :klass, "question"

  paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 10
end
```